# Many preview and beta tags sidebar

Tags: labels, tags

I have many preview and beta tags(labels) on my sidebar which I want to represent with minimal distraction of view. Currently they are all over the place. Any suggestion to represent this in much cleaner way?

[image]

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with it this way, to be honest. If the tags are there to make people aware of them then you kind of *want* them to be visible and distracting.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Actually for existing and potential users if they see many tags like these they feel the product is half cooked so want to find subtle way or to improve this a bit.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you group the beta/preview features into a category/section.

Call the category/section something like **Beta/Preview/Labs**?

This way they would be grouped and not spread out all over the place.

Or you could use a tag with muted colours so it does not stand out as much.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @michael for the suggestion. I used muted colors and small dots to represent this.